# Battery_Okay Broadcast Receiver not working as expected. How to capture the Battery_Okay Broadcast on android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

How to receive the Battery_Okay intent broadcast. I have registered a broadcast receiver for both Battery_Low and Battery_Okay intents in my manifest. The Battery_Low intent is always captured but the Battery_Okay intent never fires. I am testing with the 'Power Capacity' on the emulator to simulate the change in the battery status. In fact i tried all of the intents list [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html) and none of them worked except battery_Low. Am i missing something?

My manifest file broadcast receiver registration looks like this

```
    <receiver android:name="com.myco.library.myproduct.BatteryLowBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

     <receiver android:name="com.myco.library.myproduct.BatteryOkayBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

i also tried this in the manifest file

```
    <receiver android:name="com.myco.library.myproduct.BatteryLowBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally discovered the reason why the Battery_Okay intent was not working. I was actually writing the code in a libraby project manifest. I forgot to add the same entries in the Manifest of the app project causing it to not register properly. The Battery_low intent was registered previously and was therefore working.

I also discovered that the Battery_Okay broadcast may be fired at any battery level after it has hit low status but the device must be charging for that broadcast to be fired. The broadcast for okay wont fire if the device is not charging.